# Changed router recently, port-forward now makes internal ip's not work

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, nat

I recently got a new router from my ISP (due to the old one not supporting current speeds), and decided to configure it so the same ports were forwarded to the same devices. But I encountered an issue.

Lets start with what I **want**. I'll focus on SSH for simplicity. Say I have a device running ssh on port 22 (default) with the internal IP "A". I want to be able to do both `ssh EX` (I'll call the external IP "EX" for brevity) and (when on a device on the internal network) `ssh A` to ssh to the device. Lets claim that I got no control over the device, and that it is locked to using *only* port 22 for this, as I want to solve my problem on a router-level rather than run two SSHDs.

My **problem** with the new router is that when I port-forward port 22 to the device, then:

- If I have a port-forwarding rule for this, then as one expects `ssh EX` works, but for some reason `ssh A` (again, from device on internal network) **does not work**. *Any other port seems to work* (if I run an sshd on another port), and `ping A` works. On my old router (from same ISP) both external and (when on a device in the internal network) internal IP would work in this case.
- If I dont have any port forwarding, then as one would expect `ssh EX` doesn't work, while `ssh A` works when used from machines in the internal network. *All is as one expects.*

So my question is what might be causing this issue, and how I might resolve it? What settings should I look for in the (very graphical and confusing) GUI? Could I somehow edit the port-forwarding rule's "external host" field (currently a pure wildcard `External Host: *`) to make the rule not kill internal ones? Any other ideas?

I already contacted tech-support, but they couldn't really help me. All I got when I described my issue was that "NAT-Loopback doesnt work with port-forw.", and no help actually solving the issue.

Comment: Why is traffic from an internal device, to an internal device, being routed through your router? Are they on separate networks?

Comment: That's quite odd; can you verify with e.g. `arping` that the internal IPs resolve to the correct devices' MAC addresses, and with e.g. `tcpdump`/Wireshark that the packets are being sent/received to the correct addresses?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator They should be on the same network, unless the router splits the ethernet interface and the wifi interface without showing that in the GUI. `tracert A` has always been outputting a single hop though, so I doubt they are being routed (no entry for the router).

Comment: Which router is it?

Comment: @grawity I can't find an `arping` command for windows, and ARP.exe seems to be something different when I look at the `--help` option and compare to internet manual for arping.

Comment: @harrymc I believe the sticker says that the model is `f@st 3890v2 ch`

Comment: Perhaps this router needs to setup static internal IP addresses for port-forwarding.

Comment: @felix: It'll do – after you (normally) ping or try SSHing to the server, `arp` should show its cached MAC address. (Assuming this is all on a single LAN subnet, as you said "_the_ internal network".)

Comment: @grawity Then, the MAC address for the IP looks correct (the mac address shown is same as the devices ifconfig says it should be, and what router lists the ip's as), when doing `arp.exe -a` to list the arp entries (I assume its already there from all my messing about earlier during the day). It also looks right when looking at MAC in wireshark when doing stuff like VNC and ICMP (pinging). When trying to ssh Wireshark shows right MAC too, but gets no replies.

Comment: Does a similar packet capture _on the server_ show the same SSH connection packets arriving?

Comment: Both `tcpdump host B and port 22` and `tcpdump -i wlan0 host B and port 22` remains entirely empty. tcpdump is being run on the ssh server (the device with internal ip "A"), and the device with internal ip "B" is where I run `ssh A` from. But when doing `ssh EX` then `tcpdump -i wlan0 port 22` captures entries (`IP EX:randomport > A:22`).

Comment: @grawity In shorter words, no, the ssh server cant see any packets arriving when trying to use its internal IP.